# Cannot connect to BL thermostat if phone already paired with smartwatch

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Im developing an Android application which needs to connect to a thermostat over BLE.
To send/receive data to/from the thermostat I have to use a Uart service, so I'm writing/reading as serial.
I pool the thermostat every 300 ms.

Normally everything works fine, but I noticed that If my smartphone is connected also the my Garmin smartwatch, then I cannot connect to the thermostat.
The connect is lost.

Does a phone handle more than 1 ble connection?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Theoretically yes, a phone should be able to handle more than 1 BLE connection without an issue. What's the phone model that you are using? You can use a third party app (e.g. nRF Connect) and try connecting to multiple devices to test if the issue is with your phone's capability to connect to more than one device.